# Data not being processed when user uses a single quotation in an input/textarea

Tags: php, sql

I wasn't too sure on how to word the title, so I'll try my best to explain here.

I've created a register system and came across a bug that I never took into consideration when developing the system.
When a user types in the input boxes or a textarea, if they use single quotations the data won't be sent to the database as it will be closing the query.

This is my query code:

```
mysqli_query($uys, "INSERT INTO users SET bandname='$bandname', genre='$genre', location='$location', bio='$bio', password='$password', email='$email', ip='$ip'");
```

Of course if they don't use single quotations, there will be no error. They can use double quotes fine.

My variables are like this:

```
$bandname = $_POST['bandname'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
```

What is a way around this? I'm not the best with PHP, still learning so your help will be amazing and will help me lots.

**Sorry if this wasn't well explained, if you're confused on what I mean I'll try my best to explain it better**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a serious issue. What you face here is a **wide open** [**SQL INJECTION**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

You concatenate a query from unsanitized strings - this might lead to any kinds of troubles, where the **smallest** is *getting your whole database deleted*...

**Don't** concatenate query strings without using **proper** sanitization! In this case, [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) is the *proper* solution.

The most recommendable (is that a word?) solution is using [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) wherever possible:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users SET bandname=?, genre=?, location=?, bio=?, password=?, email=?, ip=?");

$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $bandname, $genre, $location, $bio, $password, $email, $ip);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Note:** sanitization is still important from a *content* point of view, to prevent issues like XSS attacks, or Javascript injection to pages...

(Also, using **PDO** promises independence of databases too, it is worth checking it out...)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot and thanks for the information on SQL injections too; now to improve my security!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the single-quote with 2 single-quotes, like this:

```
str_replace("'", "\''", $bandname);
```

before sending the string to SQL.  It will then show in the SQL table as a single-quote.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man. I'm not too sure on how I would implement that into my code. I have added my variables into my description, if you could, could you please explain how I could do this? I looked ta the php.net's article but it didn't help sadly.

Comment: Just put that line in the php code before the call to mysqli_query.  You need to do it for all of the strings that could have a single-quote in them.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$bandname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['bandname']);
$genre = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['genre']);
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);

mysqli_query($uys, "INSERT INTO users SET bandname='$bandname', genre='$genre', location='$location', bio='$bio', password='$password', email='$email', ip='$ip'");`
```

You need to escape your strings, otherwise it's possible to attack your database with [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).